# I want to save HTML Entity (hex) from bs4 beautifulSoup object into a file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

## The problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a=BeautifulSoup('<p class="t5">&#x20b9; 10,000 or $ 133.46</p>')
b=open('file.html','w')
b.write(str(a))
```

The result is

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 19038: character maps to <undefined>`
This is the problem because of this `&#x20b9;` and it does not occur when we change the bs4 object to str but it occurs when we write it inside a file.

## What have I tried

1. [Convert HTML entities into Unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)
2. [How to convert a bs4.element.ResultSet to strings? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968562/how-to-convert-a-bs4-element-resultset-to-strings-python)
3. [Convert an amount to Indian Notation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951552/convert-an-amount-to-indian-notation-in-python)
4. [How do I unescape HTML entities in a string in Python 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1)

## What can be the solution

Converting a BeautifulSoup object into a string without changing the & #x20b9; sign into ₹
( Which by the way str() method does ). And then saving the string into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encoding='utf-8'` on file

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a=BeautifulSoup('<p class="t5">&#x20b9; 10,000 or $ 133.46</p>')

with open(filename,'w', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    infile.write(str(a))  # OR infile.write(a.prettify())
```

**Output:**

```
<p class="t5">₹ 10,000 or $ 133.46</p>
```

Comment: It worked. But can you explain why and what is the logic behind this encoding pattern?