# How to keep html entity such as `&#9746` intact in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My goal is to read an html document using beautiful soup, add `ids` to some tags and write the html back to file.

The html document has html entities such as `&#9746` representing `☒`. When I create a beautiful soup object, the html entity gets converted to `☒`. When I write the soup back to html using `str(soup)`, the html file contains `☒` instead of `&#9746`. Opening this in a browser yields `â˜’` when I want `☒`.

I tried using `str(soup.encode(formatter='html'))`, where it did convert to UTF-8 encoding, but the html in the browser shows `\xe2\x98\x92`.

I'm guessing there is something simple that I'm missing. Any thoughts, on how to keep the special characters in the original document intact after processing it in beautiful soup?

Comment: Is there a `<meta>` tag specifying the used encoding? If not, maybe adding one would help.

Comment: I need process large number of files. Some do but most of them don't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is quite simple actually as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67268086/4029467).

Just have to use `encoding='utf-8'`. Answer from the link:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a=BeautifulSoup('<p class="t5">&#9746; &#x20b9; 10,000 or $ 133.46</p>')

with open(filename,'w', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    infile.write(str(a))  # OR infile.write(a.prettify())
```