# I'm getting error when trying to convert Html to JSON using python with beautiful soup

Tags: python, json, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from this website "https://quranromanurdu.com/chapter/1" , I want only text or content from id-contentpara and return that content in JSON format, this below code gives html content but i want that to convert to JSON. I tried to convert but I'm getting error , please somebody help me to clear this  error

python code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import codecs

URL = "https://quranromanurdu.com/chapter/1"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"id":"contentpara"})

data0 = json.loads(table)
print(data0)
```

Error

```
line 24, in <module>
    data0 = json.loads(table)
  File "C:\Users\arbazalx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ResultSet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
... your code ...
table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"id":"contentpara"})

values = list(filter(None, table[0].text.split('\n')))
values = list(filter(None, [value.replace("\xa0", "") for value in values[1:]]))

d = {}
for item in values:
    key, value = item.split('.', maxsplit=1)
    d[key] = value
```

Output:

```
{'1': ' Allah ke naam se jo Rehman o Raheem hai.',
 '2': ' Tareef Allah hi ke liye hai jo tamaam qayinaat ka Rubb hai.',
 '3': ' Rehman aur Raheem hai.',
 '4': ' Roz e jaza ka maalik hai.',
 '5': ' Hum teri hi ibadat karte hain aur tujh hi se madad maangte hain.',
 '6': ' Humein seedha raasta dikha.',
 '7': ' Un logon ka raasta jinpar tu nay inam farmaya, jo maatoob nahin huey (na unka jinpar tera gazab hota raha) , jo bhatke huey nahin hain.'}
```

Comment: im getting below error if i change the content

Comment: key, value = item.split('.', maxsplit=1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @Arbazali Which content have you changed? This approach will only be for this particular website.

Comment: i didnt touch above mentioned part , if fetch other chapters like chapter 88 im getting error as above mentioned ,but same for other chapter error doesn't throw, P.S here mentioned chapter i.e 1 doesnt throw that error and thank you for help 

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what's wrong, `findAll` returns a ResultSet which you need to convert to a `str`, this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20969389/16716191. Also `findAll` was renamed to `find_all`.